# How to set the default embed image size

Tags: images, media, wysiwyg

When a user adds media to the WYSIWYG, is there a way to set the default image size to large?

It defaults to medium, I'd like this to be "large" without the user having to change the value.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you add this to functions.php, this will update the options as set.

```
function custom_image_size() {
    // Set default values for the upload media box
    update_option('image_default_align', 'center' );
    update_option('image_default_size', 'large' );

}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'custom_image_size');
```

You can update the options as you need.